# Using % steam inside variables of your Makefiles prerequisites

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I often find myself wanting to refer to the stem not in the recipe but int the prerequisites themselves.

For example here I was playing around with some python code that scans the .cpp and .hpp files of the executable source code, in a recursive fashion, to detect what objects it depends from. The script itself works pretty well but I can't figure out how to connect it with the makefile since the input varies.

```
$(TESTS): bin/tests/%_a : bin/obj/%.o $(foreach var, $(shell python3 ./autoInc.py ./src/lib/%.cpp), bin/obj/$(var).o)
    @echo "#---------------------------"
    @echo "# Linking $@ "
    $(CC) -o $@ $^
```

(Here the makefile executes `./autoInc.py ./src/lib/%.cpp` without substitution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the form:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(TESTS): %_a : $$(foreach var, $$(shell whatever $$*.cpp), $$(var).o)
    ...
```

I advise you to get it working with a very simple toy rule, before trying to incorporate your python.